# sql "Group By" and "Having"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to work through some questions and im not sure how to do the following

> **Q:** Find the hard drive sizes that are equal among two or more PCs.

its q15 on this [site](http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref).

The database scheme consists of four tables:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

any pointers would be appreciated.

**Edit:** here is a list of all the hard drives in the pc table along with what the correct answer should be.

[image]

Comment: i know, hence why i posted most of the info in the original question and only included the link in the event someone had already registered.

Comment: When you say find the harddrive sizes that are equal among two or more PCs, you mean PCs right?  therefore Product, Laptop and Printer tables are irrelevant.

Comment: This is a 'find duplicates' problem, which ironically, is duplicated elsewhere; e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197111/fastest-get-duplicates-sql-script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this ?

```
Select PC.hd From PC
group by PC.hd
Having Count(PC.hd) >= 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.hd
  FROM PC p1
  JOIN PC p2
    ON p1.code <> p2.code
 WHERE p1.hd = p2.hd
```

Comment: Hi Petar, it came back with the following error :Ambiguous column name 'hd'.

Comment: Change the first line to "Select distinct p1.hd" and it works. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: pc.code is primary key.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.hd
  FROM pc a
 WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM pc b
         WHERE a.hd = b.hd
           AND a.code != b.code)
```

Comment: The code of the pc. `a` is an alias of the table pc. Also could you try running my query if it works. I am interested in:)

Comment: think i need a break. Cheers Petar!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`select hd from pc group by hd having count(hd)>1`

i registered and tried this, it says right.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT hd FROM PC GROUP BY hd HAVING COUNT(hd)>1
```

Right.

The result of Your query:

```
hd
5.0
8.0
10.0
14.0
20.0
```