# SQL:finding duplicate entries within a group (with a variable number of elements)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table of groups (GROUPS) defined by the group_id (PK) and some other fields. 
Each group may consist of a variable number of elements and their values. This group composition is stored in a second table (GROUP_COMPOSITION) that has a PK field (counter),a field for the group_id, a field for the element name and a field for the value of the element name.

For example:

```
Table of groups:
groupId
g1
g2

Table of Group composition:

PK     groupID       Element_Name    Element_Value
1      g1            Material        A
2      g1            Temperature     37
3      g2            Color           white
4      g2            Temperature     50
5      g2            Material        B          
6      g3            Material        C
7      g4            Color           Red
```

So, if trying to insert a "new group" (g5) exclusively defined by Material=B and Color=white and Temperature =50, i would like to identify it as a repeated group (g2).

I would like to prevent duplicate "group composition" insertion in the second table, where group composition is defined by the total number of elements and their values.

I am thinking of a INTERSECT query for all posible elements to be inserted, but not sure whether this is the optimal way.

This is related to the post [SQL to find duplicate entries (within a group)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182544/sql-to-find-duplicate-entries-within-a-group), but in this case, the criteria to find duplicate insertion was based on the number of elements (not on their nature).

I would really apprettiate any help

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to understand exactly what you're asking if you provided some sample data...

Comment: Thanks, example added (hope it helps...)

Comment: Nice question that shows why EAV is hard. Do you know exactly how many  elements there are?

Comment: No, depending on the group (defined by the user requirements) the number of elements will range from 1 to x

Answer (score 1):

I think I would build a function and go the intersection route. I guess you could also build a string to associate each group with a value representing all the group data. Then apply the same function to your candidate group and check for a match on the elements. Here is a Postgresql example of a possible aggegation:

```
SELECT g.groupid, array_to_string(g.element_array, ',') elements
  FROM (SELECT o.groupid, array_agg(o.element_name ||'='|| o.element_value) AS element_array
      FROM (SELECT groupid, element_name, element_value
              FROM composition
              ORDER BY 1, 2) o
      GROUP BY groupid) g
  ORDER BY groupid


 groupid |          elements
---------+---------------------------------------
 g1      | Material=A,Temperature=37
 g2      | Color=white,Material=B,Temperature=50
 g3      | Material=C
 g4      | Color=Red
```

The inner ordering is to ensure it generates consistently. Seems Oracle 11gR2 has a LISTAGG function for string concatenation which could be useful. Or you could build your own aggregate function to do this. If this data is relatively static, you might want to pre-compute and store on insert rather than regenerate with each query.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data seems to indicate there is a fairly stable range of properties to these groups, why not make them first-class citizens instead and promote them to columns?

```
groupid | Material | Temperature | Color
--------+----------+-------------+-----------
g1      | A        | 37          | <null>
g2      | B        | 50          | White
g3      | C        | <null>      | <null>
g4      | <null>   | <null>      | Red
```

It wouldn't be too hard to dynamically add columns as needed if you were so inclined, but I'm a little curious as to how you want to define a group as "repeated"? Whenever the attributes of a new group has at least one corresponding atribute in the existing group? If so, the query would be really simple:

```
select groupid from table where
Material=B and
Color=White
```

If there are any returned rows, then you already have a group with at least those properties.