# SQL query to find duplicate invoices

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find duplicate invoices in my accounts payable department.  I have tried writing the query to find common errors several different ways, but the best query I have written so far has a lot of false positives in results. It is common for invoices to pay by accident under different vendors or different company numbers and even sometimes to the same vendor.

```
SELECT INVOICE,
--VENDOR
IDVENDORNAME,
--INVOICEAMOUNT,
COUNT(INVOICE),
SUM(INVOICEAMOUNT)
FROM payablesinvoice
WHERE IDVENDORNAME != 'UNKNOWN'
AND APCOMPANY != 0
HAVING COUNT(INVOICE) >= 2
GROUP BY INVOICE, VENDOR, IDVENDORNAME, INVOICEAMOUNT;
```

Comment: you have misplaced the `having by` clause.put it after `group by`.

Comment: Something wrong with how you input sample code.  However, it looks close using HAVING COUNT(INVOICE) >= 2.  Please correct post to be more legible.

Comment: @brenners1302 spotted it.  HAVING comes after GROUP BY

Comment: Can you [edit] to include more specific information about false positive examples? Also, it looks like you have several of the `GROUP BY` fields commented out of the `SELECT`.

Comment: The false positives I'm getting are primarily invoices that don't have duplicate invoices at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to find duplicate entries (within a group)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182544/sql-to-find-duplicate-entries-within-a-group)

Answer (score 0):

Move `HAVING` to after `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT Invoice, COUNT(Invoice), ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY Invoice, ...
HAVING COUNT(Invoice) >= 2
```

Note that the `...` is just filler for your **actual** code.

Also, general rule of thumb is only `GROUP BY` fields in `SELECT` statement.