# How does one write a query that organizes by merchant then by found duplicates?

Tags: sql, database, self-join

I am hunting for duplicate customerids and want to display them by merchant. I know this needs a self join but can't get the syntax right.

This query shows me the items that have duplicates.

```
Select MerchId, CustId, Count(CustId) 
from Customers
Group by MerchId, CustId
Having Count(CustId)> 1
```

And this query shows me all the dups for a specific merchant.

```
SELECT  c.MerchId, c.CustId 
FROM Customers c
WHERE CustId IN 
(SELECT c.CustId FROM Customers AS c
WHERE c.MerchId = @mid 
group by c.CustId having count(1) > 1)
and c.MerchId = @mid
order by CustId
```

But what I want to see is info displayed as:

```
MerchId, CustId, Address, Phone     
1        01     
1        01     
1        02     
1        02     
1        03     
1        03     
2        01     
2        01     
2        02     
2        02
```

assume n merchants with n customers. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL to find duplicate entries (within a group)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182544/sql-to-find-duplicate-entries-within-a-group)

Comment: (Obviously,) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS 'site:stackoverflow.com sql find duplicates per group' First google, first hit, 2008.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the process I went through before posting. Didn't come across that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join your query to the table:

```
select c.merchid, c.custid, c.address, c.phone 
from customers c inner join (
  select merchid, custid 
  from customers
  group by merchId, custId
  having count(custid)> 1
) g on g.merchid = c.merchid and g.custid = c.custid
```

or by explicitly counting for each row (less efficient but easier to read):

```
select c.merchid, c.custid, c.address, c.phone 
from customers c
where (
  select count(*) from customers
  where merchid = c.merchid and custid = c.custid
) > 1
```